# How find the length of the longest substring?

Tags: javascript

Need find the length of the longest substring that consists of the same letter. For example, line "aaabbcaaaa" contains four substrings with the same letters "aaa", "bb","c" and "aaaa".

i found two way to do that, but all not so good;

At first way i don't make check previos similar letters here `sdsffffse`;
Because i check only current element and second element `if(line[i] === line[i+1])`.

At second way i fail when i try to check how many `aa` i found in that string `abababaab` but in object i add all `a` letters and length = 5;

```js
function longRepeat(line) {
    let count = {};
   let letter = [];
  for (let i=0; i<line.length; i++) {
   count[line[i]] = i;
    if(line[i] === line[i+1]){
          letter.push([line[i], line[i+1]])
    }
  }

  
/*
second way
for (let x of line) {
    count[x] = ~~count[x] + 1;
 } */
  
  return letter;
}

console.log(longRepeat('sdsffffse')); f = 4
console.log(longRepeat('ddvvrwwwrggg')); = 3
console.log(longRepeat('abababaab')); // last two a = 2
```

Comment: Don't `count` them by letter, you don't want a histogram. Split the string into an array of the substrings, then find the longest one amongst those.

Comment: @Bergi i make split only by one letter in cycle or covert all string to array by method .split();

Comment: Split into groups by iterating and comparing to the previous letter. If you want to be clever, `split` is not the tool but `.match(/(.)\1*/g)` will be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
function longestSubstr(str) {
  if (!str) return 0
  let maxL = 1
  let curL = 1
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++) {
    let cur = str[i]
    let next = str[i + 1]
    if (cur === next) {
      curL++
    } else {
      if (maxL < curL) maxL = curL
      curL = 1
    }
  }
  if (maxL < curL) maxL = curL
  return maxL
}

console.log(longestSubstr("abababaab")) // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using regular expressions.

```js
function func(line) {
  let reg = /(\w)\1+/g;
  let longest = line.match(reg).sort((a, b) => {
    a.length - b.length
  }).pop();
  console.log(line + ' : ' + longest);
}

func('ddvvrwwwrggg');
func('sdsffffse');
func('abababaab');
func('aaabbcaaaa');
func('aaaasdfbbbbyyyweryyyuurweuuuuuu');
```

`/(\w)\1+/g` will match a sequence of the same character, using the `match()` method we get all the sequences, sort them by length, and get the last item in the array, i didn't know what to do in case of equal length, so i'll leave that you, i'm merely presenting an idea, and it's for you to improve it :)

Comment: Yea, when i start to do that function i think to use regex, but in work with regex i such noob)

Comment: i have to admit, regular expressions can be intimidating, but you'll get the hang of it

Answer (score 0):

```
#python
def long_repeat(line):
    line = line.lower()
    max = 1
    if len(line) == 0:
        return 0
    for i in range(0, len(line) - 1):
        count = 1
        while line[i] == line[i + 1]:
            count += 1
            if max < count:
                max = count
            if i < len(line) - 2:
                i += 1
            else:
                break
    return max
```

Comment: Please try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Thanks